# Understanding minzinc

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

I am trying to solve my problem and I used Hakan's code as example from here http://hakank.org/minizinc/scheduling_with_multiple_workers.mzn

I dont know what exactly mean this part of code, where `machine[t]=m`. Could anyone explain me this part?

```
forall(m in 1..num_machines) (
     % check the memory of the times when a task is run on the machine
     forall(tt in 1..max_time) (
        machine_used_ram[m,tt] = sum([memory[t]*(machine[t]=m)*(tt in start_time[t]..end_time[t]) | t in 1..num_tasks])
```

Comment: It is a boolean value of comparison. You can see explanation in the comment: sum only memory when the task was on that machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(machine[t]=m)` is a Boolean expression converted to `1`, if `machine[t]` is equal to `m`. Otherwise, it is `0`.

So, `(machine[t]=m)*(tt in start_time[t]..end_time[t])` is selecting all memory values to be summed-up which belong to the machine and time of the outer `forall` loops.

Comment: I'd like ask you one more question. What do "sum" in this same row? I know that it is "summing" something, but what?

Comment: `[memory[t]*(machine[t]=m)*(tt in start_time[t]..end_time[t]) | t in 1..num_tasks]` is an array of `num_tasks` elements, one for every value of `t` from `1` to `num_tasks`. `sum()` adds them all up.